# PHP 7.2 deprecated: while = each() loop without $value

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, each, deprecated

As **each()** loop is deprecated since **PHP 7.2**, how to update the below **while(() = each())** loop without $value?

Without the **$value** I can't get foreach loop to work. In addition **while($products_id = $this->contents)** results in infinite loop.

Thank you!

```
$total_items = 0;

reset($this->contents);
while (list($products_id, ) = each($this->contents)) {
    $total_items += $this->get_quantity($products_id);
}
```